# Root partition also mounted at /mnt leading to full partition

Tags: mount

I have a weird situation where my root partition (/dev/sda9) is also mounted (at /mnt/sda9) resulting in the partition being full. This is a test partition so I will overwrite it but I am curious to know if anyone has any insights about this.
There is no fstab entry mounting /dev/sda9 to anywhere but root. Some code snips below -

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           766M   40M  727M   6% /run
/dev/sda9        20G   20G     0 100% /
tmpfs           3.8G  4.0K  3.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.8G     0  3.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb1       1.8T  1.8T  4.7G 100% /media/2TB-01
/dev/sdc1       2.8T  2.8T   18G 100% /media/XBMC
/dev/sda5       621G  577G   45G  93% /mnt/Data
tmpfs           766M     0  766M   0% /run/user/1000
```

```
# sudo du -hsx /* | sort -rh | head -n 40
7.3G    /mnt
6.4G    /var
3.7G    /usr
1.1G    /lib
1.1G    /home
108M    /boot
13M     /sbin
12M     /etc
12M     /bin
5.8M    /lib32
4.3M    /media
2.9M    /root
88K     /run
36K     /tmp
16K     /lost+found
8.0K    /srv
8.0K    /snap
...
```

```
$ sudo du -hsx /mnt/* | sort -rh | head -n 35
577G    /mnt/Data
7.3G    /mnt/sda9
20K     /mnt/boot-sav
4.0K    /mnt/sda8
4.0K    /mnt/sda6
4.0K    /mnt/sandisk
```

```
$ ls /mnt/sda9
bin  cdrom  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  initrd.img.old  lib  lib32  lib64  lost+found  opt  proc  resolv.conf  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  usr  var  vmlinuz  vmlinuz.old
```

```
# sudo umount /mnt/sda9
umount: /mnt/sda9: not mounted.
# sudo umount /dev/sda9
# ls /mnt/sda9
bin  cdrom  dev  etc  home  initrd.img  initrd.img.old  lib  lib32  lib64  lost+found  opt  proc  resolv.conf  root  run  sbin  snap  srv  sys  usr  var  vmlinuz  vmlinuz.old
```

```
$ cat /proc/mounts
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
udev /dev devtmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3898600k,nr_inodes=974650,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000 0 0
tmpfs /run tmpfs rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=784212k,mode=755 0 0
/dev/sda9 / ext4 rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered 0 0
securityfs /sys/kernel/security securityfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev/shm tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
tmpfs /run/lock tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k 0 0
tmpfs /sys/fs/cgroup tmpfs ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/unified cgroup2 rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,name=systemd 0 0
pstore /sys/fs/pstore pstore rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/memory cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/devices cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/pids cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,rdma 0 0
cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer cgroup rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer 0 0
systemd-1 /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc autofs rw,relatime,fd=27,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=1594 0 0
mqueue /dev/mqueue mqueue rw,relatime 0 0
debugfs /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
hugetlbfs /dev/hugepages hugetlbfs rw,relatime,pagesize=2M 0 0
configfs /sys/kernel/config configfs rw,relatime 0 0
fusectl /sys/fs/fuse/connections fusectl rw,relatime 0 0
/dev/sdb1 /media/2TB-01 ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/sdc1 /media/XBMC xfs rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,noatime,nodiratime,attr2,inode64,allocsize=524288k,logbufs=8,noquota 0 0
/dev/sda5 /mnt/Data ext3 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 0
tmpfs /run/user/1000 tmpfs rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=784208k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0

# / was on /dev/sda9 during installation
### UUID=0b512eac-ce71-4d31-8756-ad25f01a50b3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

### UUID=08085bcd-cc21-4ab9-8420-508bc3590516     /           ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
LABEL=sda9     /           ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1


# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=2a95d85a-45fe-4584-88dd-0ee20e651ec5 none            swap    sw              0       0

# /dev/sda5 = Data
LABEL=sda-data-600gb            /mnt/Data       ext3    defaults,relatime,user_xattr            0       0
#/dev/sda5       /mnt/Data       ext3    defaults,relatime,user_xattr            0       0
#UUID=37971286-b8d3-4a1b-9f94-4008288fed6d
# Dropbox automatically adds user_xattr to the partition that holds the Dropbox folder to enable extended file attributes
# relatime means that file access times are only updated when the file is modified, not read


# /dev/sda6 = home
#LABEL=home       /home          ext3    defaults,relatime                                   0       0
#/dev/sda6       /home         ext3    defaults,relatime,user_xattr            0       0
# Dropbox automatically adds user_xattr to the partition that holds the Dropbox folder to enable extended file attributes
# relatime means that file access times are only updated when the file is modified, not each time it is read

#1TB-01
##### LABEL=HTPC_MythTV /media/MythTV_1TB xfs user,nofail,noatime,nodiratime,allocsize=512m,logbufs=8 0 0
#UUID=76f3823a-81dc-45c9-a0b7-2bc6c3beb2f8 /media/1TB-01 xfs     noatime,nodiratime,allocsize=512m,logbufs=8    0    0
#removed defaults, relatime


# XBMC
# This next line is usually the only uncommented one for this volume.
 LABEL=XBMC-3TB /media/XBMC xfs user,nofail,noatime,nodiratime,allocsize=512m,logbufs=8 0 0


# MYTHTV
#LABEL=3TB01P1-Myth /media/MythTV xfs noatime,nofail,nodiratime,allocsize=512m,logbufs=8 0 0

# 2TB-01
LABEL=2TB-01 /media/2TB-01 ext4 defaults,nofail

# Arch /dev/sda8 on /mnt/sda8
#/dev/sda8       /mnt/sda8         ext3    defaults,relatime,user_xattr            0       0

# Arch /dev/sda6 (HOME/BEN) on /dev/sda6
#/dev/sda6       /mnt/sda6         ext3    defaults,relatime,user_xattr            0       0

#Sandisk backup
### LABEL=ROOT /mnt/sandisk ext4 defaults,nofail
```

```
# blkid
/dev/sda1: LABEL="/grub" UUID="1555c5bb-a9a5-4da9-9274-fdee304ec3e8" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="0000b084-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="2a95d85a-45fe-4584-88dd-0ee20e651ec5" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="0000b084-02"
/dev/sda5: LABEL="sda-data-600gb" UUID="37971286-b8d3-4a1b-9f94-4008288fed6d" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="0000b084-05"
/dev/sda6: LABEL="home" UUID="559c6f3d-8891-414b-965c-1578f06bbf5b" SEC_TYPE="ext2" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="0000b084-06"
/dev/sda7: LABEL="mini" UUID="6b2a25de-98c2-425b-aace-1d1fcc24cb32" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0000b084-07"
/dev/sda8: LABEL="mini" UUID="4ce44df5-64f0-4b1f-90cb-4cff9b3f55f2" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0000b084-08"
/dev/sda9: LABEL="sda9" UUID="08085bcd-cc21-4ab9-8420-508bc3590516" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="0000b084-09"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="2TB-01" UUID="c23cf34b-9513-4461-a718-4b9d06f60e4b" TYPE="ext3" PARTUUID="00057fb0-01"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="XBMC-3TB" UUID="571b07eb-40c2-4d87-9d19-44f72de467fc" TYPE="xfs" PARTUUID="eb244e9e-690a-4f0e-a31d-aa9fc03eaf86"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="ROOT" UUID="81c098a4-45d9-438e-8ad5-d262e8e8f740" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="edacc4dc-01"
```

```
$ dmesg | grep mount
[    6.247070] EXT4-fs (sda9): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   11.940721] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[   12.432598] EXT4-fs (sda9): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
[   38.452416] EXT4-fs (sdb1): warning: maximal mount count reached, running e2fsck is recommended
[   38.818369] EXT4-fs (sdb1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
[   39.575054] XFS (sdc1): Ending clean mount
[   39.603079] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   39.648981] EXT4-fs (sda5): warning: mounting fs with errors, running e2fsck is recommended
[   40.020530] EXT4-fs (sda5): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: user_xattr
```

```
$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep sda9
Nov  4 10:57:45 HTPC kernel: [    1.462557]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda4 < sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 >
Nov  4 10:57:45 HTPC kernel: [    6.235204] EXT4-fs (sda9): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Nov  4 10:57:45 HTPC kernel: [   12.221009] EXT4-fs (sda9): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Nov  4 11:39:58 HTPC kernel: [    1.196425]  sda: sda1 sda2 sda4 < sda5 sda6 sda7 sda8 sda9 >
Nov  4 11:39:58 HTPC kernel: [    6.279665] EXT4-fs (sda9): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
Nov  4 11:39:58 HTPC kernel: [   12.298919] EXT4-fs (sda9): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Nov  4 12:00:01 HTPC CRON[2476]: (root) CMD (rsync -avxHAWX --numeric-ids --exclude-from '/home/ben/Scripts/RsyncRootExcList.txt'   / /mnt/sda9  >/dev/null  )
```

```
$ ls /etc/udev/rules.d/
70-persistent-net.rules

$  sudo cat 70-persistent-net.rules | less

cat: 70-persistent-net.rules: No such file or directory
```

```
$ gio mount -li
Drive(0): WDC WD7500AACS-00ZJB0
  Type: GProxyDrive (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
  ids:
   unix-device: '/dev/sda'
  themed icons:  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
  symbolic themed icons:  [drive-harddisk-symbolic]  [drive-symbolic]  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
  is_removable=0
  is_media_removable=0
  has_media=1
  is_media_check_automatic=1
  can_poll_for_media=0
  can_eject=0
  can_start=0
  can_stop=0
  start_stop_type=shutdown
  sort_key=00coldplug/00fixed/sd____a
  Volume(0): mini
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
    ids:
     class: 'device'
     unix-device: '/dev/sda8'
     uuid: '4ce44df5-64f0-4b1f-90cb-4cff9b3f55f2'
     label: 'mini'
    uuid=4ce44df5-64f0-4b1f-90cb-4cff9b3f55f2
    themed icons:  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
    symbolic themed icons:  [drive-harddisk-symbolic]  [drive-symbolic]  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
    can_mount=1
    can_eject=0
    should_automount=0
    sort_key=gvfs.time_detected_usec.1604631000947770
  Volume(1): mini
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
    ids:
     class: 'device'
     unix-device: '/dev/sda7'
     uuid: '6b2a25de-98c2-425b-aace-1d1fcc24cb32'
     label: 'mini'
    uuid=6b2a25de-98c2-425b-aace-1d1fcc24cb32
    themed icons:  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
    symbolic themed icons:  [drive-harddisk-symbolic]  [drive-symbolic]  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
    can_mount=1
    can_eject=0
    should_automount=0
    sort_key=gvfs.time_detected_usec.1604631000947857
  Volume(2): home
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
    ids:
     class: 'device'
     unix-device: '/dev/sda6'
     uuid: '559c6f3d-8891-414b-965c-1578f06bbf5b'
     label: 'home'
    uuid=559c6f3d-8891-414b-965c-1578f06bbf5b
    themed icons:  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
    symbolic themed icons:  [drive-harddisk-symbolic]  [drive-symbolic]  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
    can_mount=1
    can_eject=0
    should_automount=0
    sort_key=gvfs.time_detected_usec.1604631000947938
  Volume(3): /grub
    Type: GProxyVolume (GProxyVolumeMonitorUDisks2)
    ids:
     class: 'device'
     unix-device: '/dev/sda1'
     uuid: '1555c5bb-a9a5-4da9-9274-fdee304ec3e8'
     label: '/grub'
    uuid=1555c5bb-a9a5-4da9-9274-fdee304ec3e8
    themed icons:  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
    symbolic themed icons:  [drive-harddisk-symbolic]  [drive-symbolic]  [drive-harddisk]  [drive]
    can_mount=1
    can_eject=0
    should_automount=0
    sort_key=gvfs.time_detected_usec.1604631000948018
```

Comment: How does gnome-disks show it mounting? gnome-disks also has mount options in it.

Comment: I don't know. I don't have it installed (xfce) - and I can't install it or get a graphic display because the partition is full!

Comment: I know you mentioned you've examined it, but i'd still like to see /etc/fstab. You should look at things like `blkid` and make note of UUIDs. look through `dmesg` in the areas where the mounts are being established. look through /var/log/syslog during the boot time. check in /etc/udev/rules.d/ for any entries or rules you may have established. look at your grub entries. look at `gio mount -li`. I see you have a few things mounted under /mnt, you must have done some configurations for those somewhere, check those. Are you sure youre not mistakenly mounting/bind "/" to something else post boot?

Comment: Check your cron jobs, looks like you have a backup of / to /mnt/sda9 (just a directory), which never completes and fills up root.

Comment: agreed @ubfan1 ..... you are periodically copying your / into itself... your backup (/mnt/sda9) is most likely incomplete so you may want to delete it... and then fix the cron job to back it up somewhere else(if that truly is what you intended)

Comment: Thanks for the further comments. I added some more output to the main post in response to @Wu-Tangs comments. Regarding the cron job - yes, I do have one - although I turned it off before this issue arose. (I'm curious as to how you could tell about the cron job from the output I posted?). My system runs on sdd1. I want to keep a regularly updated backup of sdd1, which is what sda9 is for. In sdd1 I mount /dev/sda9 as /mnt/sda9 and have a periodic rsync job to back it up to /mnt/sda9. I don't understand how that results in a /mnt/sda9 in sda9? I exclude /mnt from the rsync job.

Comment: Maybe there is some terminology confusion? There is no "mounting" happening. From what I see, your system actually runs on /dev/sda9(not sdd1), and you are intending to mount sdd1(which i think is the backup...the `fstab` output is cut off) at the FOLDER /mnt/sda9. Then you are rsyncing the entire "/" directory into that FOLDER.. You do not show ANYWHERE (also,again the fstab output cutoff) that /dev/sdd1 is actually mounted. So according to your logs you are copying your entire "/", minus your exclusion file, basically onto itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Thanks. You guys have nailed it - from that syslog line about the cron job. That cron job isn't meant to run in sda9 - it is meant to run in my live system sdd1 - to create the backup to sda9. (All this output is taken while booted/ chrooted into sda9 because that is where the problem was). The sdd1 crontab file got rsync'd to sda9 and because I didn't comment out the rsync line in the sda9 copy of the sdd1 crontab - and because I was booted into sda9 when the crontab ran the rsync job - sda9 did indeed copy itself into the /mnt/sda9 folder. Thanks for your help with this. I have now deleted the contents of /mnt/sda9, commented out the rsync cron line in sda9 and will need to add the cron folder (/var/spool/cron/crontabs)to my exclusion list in sdd1. How do I mark the title as solved?

Comment: Accept your own answer, maybe after a few days delay, to mark as solved.